# lambda is creating new columns when criteria is met rather than rows

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Someone kindly answered my previous question which was working until expanding it on our actual dataset (which has about 5m rows). My own for loop is very slow on that data so hoping the lambda solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70348661/looping-through-a-filtered-dataframe-to-see-if-a-value-is-in-a-list-column?noredirect=1#comment124358528_70348661) will work. However, when using the below dataset:

```
date       customerID   saved   purchased   savedProduct    purchasedProduct
2021-01-01  456789        1        0          11223344           0
2021-01-01  456789        1        0          55667788           0
2021-01-03  456789        0        1           0              11223344
2021-01-03  456789        0        1           0              28373827
2021-02-05  456710        1        0          55667789           0
2021-02-05  456710        1        0          55667790           0
2021-02-09  456710        1        0          556677288          0
2021-02-05  2727228       1        0          55667789           0
2021-02-05  2727228       0        1          0               11223344
2021-02-05  2727228       0        1          0               28373827
2021-02-09  2727228       0        1          0               55667789
2021-02-09  2727228       0        1          0               28373827
```

Which is created with this code:

```
d = {'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-03', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-09', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-09', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-10'], 
     'customerID': ['456789', '456789', '456789', '456710', '456710', '456710', '2727228', '2727228', '2727228', '2727210', '2727210'],
    'saved':[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
     'purchased': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
     'savedProduct': [11223344, 55667788, 0, 55667789, 55667790, 556677288, 55667789, 0, 0, 3828292, 0], 
     'purchasedProduct': [[0], [0], [11223344, 28373827], [0], [0], [0], [0], [11223344, 28373827], [55667789, 28373827], [0], [3828292]]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d).explode('purchasedProduct').reset_index(drop=True)
```

When running the solution provided however, which is this:

```
df2.groupby('customerID').apply(
  lambda df: df.apply(
    lambda x: np.nan if x.savedProduct == 0 else df.loc[df.purchasedProduct == x.savedProduct, 'date'], axis = 1))
```

I get a resulting table that creates a new column every time it finds a match, like so:

```
2            10 13
2021-01-03  NaN NaN
NaN         NaN NaN
NaN         NaN NaN
NaN         NaN NaN
NaN         NaN NaN
NaN         NaN NaN
NaN         NaN NaN
NaN         2021-02-09  NaN
```

I've tried trouble-shooting it but my knowledge of lambdas is very basic. My (edited) code does work for what I need it to do, but as soon as the dataset gets to 100k+ rows it takes over an hour to run on Databricks and I need it to run on data that's around 5m rows as mentioned. Is there any way to get the lambda to do, where I would:

```
df2['purchasedDates'] = df2.groupby('customerID').apply(
      lambda df: df.apply(
        lambda x: np.nan if x.savedProduct == 0 else df.loc[df.purchasedProduct == x.savedProduct, 'date'], axis = 1))
```

Would return (expected output):

```
purchasedDates
2021-01-03
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
2021-02-09
etc
```

Thanks for any help and hope this is appropriate, I would've edited the prev question but saw you're not meant to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can get the column you need with:

1. `merge` the DataFrame with itself to get the purchased date of the saved product.
2. Keep only the required columns and rename to match original DataFrame columns.

```
merged = df2[df2["savedProduct"].ne(0)].merge(df2, 
                                              left_on=["customerID", "savedProduct"], 
                                              right_on=["customerID", "purchasedProduct"], 
                                              how="left")
output = merged.rename(columns={"customerID": "customerID_x", "date_y": "purchasedDate_x"}).filter(like="_x")
output = output.rename(columns={col:col.rstrip("_x") for col in output.columns})

>>> output
         date customerID  saved  ...  savedProduct purchasedProduct purchasedDate
0  2021-01-01     456789      1  ...      11223344                0    2021-01-03
1  2021-01-01     456789      1  ...      55667788                0           NaN
2  2021-02-05     456710      1  ...      55667789                0           NaN
3  2021-02-05     456710      1  ...      55667790                0           NaN
4  2021-02-09     456710      1  ...     556677288                0           NaN
5  2021-02-05    2727228      1  ...      55667789                0    2021-02-09
6  2021-02-05    2727210      1  ...       3828292                0    2021-02-10

[7 rows x 7 columns]
```